# sqlite3 OperationalError: near "m": syntax error

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

df = pd.read_csv('liked_songs.csv')
!sqlite3 spotify.db < spotify.sql
connection = sqlite3.connect('spotify.db')
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ','_')
cursor = connection.cursor()

for index in df.index:
    sr = df.iloc[index]
    cursor = cursor.execute(f"""INSERT INTO spotify (SpotifyID, ArtistID, Track_Name, 
                           Album_Name, Artist_Name, Release_Date, Duration,Popularity, Genres)
                        VALUES ('{sr.SpotifyID}', '{sr.Artist_ID}', '{sr.Track_Name}', 
                                '{sr.Album_Name}', '{sr.Artist_Name}', '{sr.Release_Date}',
                                '{sr.Duration}', '{sr.Popularity}', '{sr.Genres}')""")
```

I'm using pandas to import a .csv file and sqlite3 to enter data into a database made from a SQL script.[Image of SQL script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpV0i.png)

Comment: Probably one of the values contains an embedded quote.  This is why you should always use [parameter subtitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python) when passing values to `cursor.execute`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use [`to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

df = pd.read_csv('liked_songs.csv')
connection = sqlite3.connect('spotify.db')
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ','_')
df.to_sql('spotify', connection, if_exists='replace', index=None)
```